# Python Inspect - Lookup the data type for a property in a GAE db.model Class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, reflection, inspection

```
class Employee(db.Model):
  firstname           = db.StringProperty()       
  lastname            = db.StringProperty()       
  address1            = db.StringProperty() 
  timezone            = db.FloatProperty()     #might be -3.5 (can contain fractions)


class TestClassAttributes(webapp.RequestHandler):
  """
  Enumerate attributes of a db.Model class 
  """
  def get(self): 
     for item in Employee.properties(): 
         self.response.out.write("<br/>" + item)
         #for subitem in item.__dict__: 
         #   self.response.out.write("<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;--" + subitem)
```

The above will give me a list of the property names for the variable "item". 
My idea of `item.__dict__` didn't work because `item` was a `str`.
How can I then display the data field type for each property, such as `db.FloatProperty()` for the property called `timezone`?

GAE = Google App Engine - but I'm sure the same answer would work for any class.

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate using "for name, property in Employee.properties().items()". The property argument is the Property instance, which you can compare using instanceof.

Answer (score 1):

For problems like these, the interactive Python shell is really handy.  If you had used it to poke around at your Employee object, you might have discovered the answer to your question through trial and error.

Something like:

```
>>> from groups.models import Group
>>> Group.properties()
{'avatar': <google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0x19f73b0>,
 'created_at': <google.appengine.ext.db.DateTimeProperty object at 0x19f7330>,
 'description': <google.appengine.ext.db.TextProperty object at 0x19f7210>,
 'group_type': <google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0x19f73d0>}
```

From that you know that the `properties()` method of a `db.Model` object returns a `dict` mapping the model's property names to the actual property objects they represent.

Comment: I believe that is what I showed in my question, i.e. I was iterating the properties().  I'm looking for how to get to the data type.  I guess I could figure out anything with trial and error - thus the use of StackOverflow to save time.

Comment: I guess I was just trying to point out that dropping into the interactive shell might have pointed you in the right direction by showing you that the properties() method returns a dictionary, which you would (generally speaking, I think) want to iterate over differently (using .items() to get both the key and the value).  And it would have shown you that the values stored in that dictionary are exactly the values you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I add the same problem, and the first 2 answers did not help me 100%.
I was not able to get the type information, from the meta data of the class or the
instance property, which is bizarre. So I had to use a dictionary.

The method GetType() will return the type of the property as a string.

Here is my answer:

```
class RFolder(db.Model):
     def GetPropertyTypeInstance(self, pname):
        for name, property in self.properties().items():
            if name==pname:
                return property
        return None

    def GetType(self, pname):
        t = self.GetPropertyTypeInstance(pname)
        return RFolder.__DB_PROPERTY_INFO[type(t)]

    __DB_PROPERTY_INFO = {

        db.StringProperty           :"String",
        db.ByteStringProperty       :"ByteString",
        db.BooleanProperty          :"Boolean",
        db.IntegerProperty          :"Integer",
        db.FloatProperty            :"Float",
        db.DateTimeProperty         :"DateTime",
        db.DateProperty             :"Date",
        db.TimeProperty             :"Time",
        db.ListProperty             :"List",
        db.StringListProperty       :"StringList",
        db.ReferenceProperty        :"Reference",
        db.SelfReferenceProperty    :"SelfReference",
        db.UserProperty             :"User",
        db.BlobProperty             :"Blob",
        db.TextProperty             :"Text",
        db.CategoryProperty         :"Category",
        db.LinkProperty             :"Link",
        db.EmailProperty            :"Email",
        db.GeoPtProperty            :"GeoPt",
        db.IMProperty               :"IM",
        db.PhoneNumberProperty      :"PhoneNumber",
        db.PostalAddressProperty    :"PostalAddress",
        db.RatingProperty           :"Rating"
    }
```